# Getting the First object of a Response.Json() object

Tags: javascript, json, object, promise

i have a this code:

```js
fetch("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?name=Rick")
    .then((response) => {
      response.json().then((data) => {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
    }).catch( (error) => {
        console.log(`Error: ${error}`)
    })
   })
```

the api in question is not important, the thing is the response.json() return a array of objects and im a little lost, i want to select a certain index to select that object but i cant, i tried multiples methods, but dont work, more than a answer simply, i want if its a possible a explanation of how works the objects with response.json() and if differs of a simple object in javascript, thanks.

Edit: here is the output of the code

```
{"info":{"count":107,"pages":6,"next":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=2&name=Rick","prev":null},"results":[{"id":1,"name":"Rick Sanchez","status":"Alive","species":"Human","type":"","gender":"Male","origin":{"name":"Earth (C-137)","url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/1"},"location":{"name":"Citadel of Ricks","url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/3"},"image":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/1.jpeg","episode":["https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/1","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/2","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/3","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/4","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/5","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/6","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/7","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/8","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/9","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/10","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/11","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/12","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/13","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/14","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/15","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/16","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/17","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/18","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/19","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/20","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/21","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/22","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/23","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/24","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/25","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/26","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/27","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/28","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/29","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/30","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/31","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/32","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/33","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/34","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/35","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/36","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/37","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/38","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/39","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/40","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/41","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/42","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/43","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/44","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/45","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/46","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/47","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/48","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/49","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/50","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/51"],"url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/1","created":"2017-11-04T18:48:46.250Z"},{"id":8,"name":"Adjudicator Rick","status":"Dead","species":"Human","type":"","gender":"Male","origin":{"name":"unknown","url":""},"location":{"name":"Citadel of Ricks","url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/3"},"image":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/8.jpeg","episode":["https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/28"],"url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/8","created":"2017-11-04T20:03:34.737Z"},{"id":15,"name":"Alien Rick","status":"unknown","species":"Alien","type":"","gender":"Male","origin":{"name":"unknown","url":""},"location":{"name":"Citadel of Ricks","url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/3"},"image":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/15.jpeg","episode":["https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/10"],"url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/15","created":"2017-11-04T20:56:13.215Z"},{"id":19,"name":"Antenna Rick","status":"unknown","species":"Human","type":"Human with antennae","gender":"Male","origin":{"name":"unknown","url":""},"location":{"name":"unknown","url":""},"image":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/19.jpeg","episode":["https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/10"],"url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/19","created":"2017-11-04T22:28:13.756Z"},{"id":22,"name":"Aqua Rick","status":"unknown","species":"Humanoid","type":"Fish-Person","gender":"Male","origin":{"name":"unknown","url":""},"location":{"name":"Citadel of Ricks","url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/3"},"image":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/22.jpeg","episode":["https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/10","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/22","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/28"],"url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/22","created":"2017-11-04T22:41:07.171Z"},{"id":48,"name":"Black Rick","status":"Alive","species":"Human","type":"","gender":"Male","origin":{"name":"unknown","url":""},"location":{"name":"Citadel of Ricks","url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/3"},"image":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/48.jpeg","episode":["https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/22","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/28"],"url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/48","created":"2017-11-05T11:15:26.044Z"},{"id":56,"name":"Bootleg Portal Chemist Rick","status":"Dead","species":"Human","type":"","gender":"Male","origin":{"name":"unknown","url":""},"location":{"name":"Citadel of Ricks","url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/3"},"image":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/56.jpeg","episode":["https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/28"],"url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/56","created":"2017-11-05T11:34:16.447Z"},{"id":69,"name":"Commander Rick","status":"Dead","species":"Human","type":"","gender":"Male","origin":{"name":"unknown","url":""},"location":{"name":"Citadel of Ricks","url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/3"},"image":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/69.jpeg","episode":["https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/22"],"url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/69","created":"2017-11-30T11:28:06.461Z"},{"id":72,"name":"Cool Rick","status":"Alive","species":"Human","type":"","gender":"Male","origin":{"name":"Earth (K-83)","url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/26"},"location":{"name":"Citadel of Ricks","url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/3"},"image":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/72.jpeg","episode":["https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/28"],"url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/72","created":"2017-11-30T11:41:11.542Z"},{"id":74,"name":"Cop Rick","status":"Alive","species":"Human","type":"","gender":"Male","origin":{"name":"unknown","url":""},"location":{"name":"Citadel of Ricks","url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/3"},"image":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/74.jpeg","episode":["https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/28"],"url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/74","created":"2017-11-30T11:48:18.950Z"},{"id":78,"name":"Cowboy Rick","status":"Alive","species":"Human","type":"","gender":"Male","origin":{"name":"unknown","url":""},"location":{"name":"Citadel of Ricks","url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/3"},"image":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/78.jpeg","episode":["https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/10","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/28"],"url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/78","created":"2017-11-30T14:15:18.347Z"},{"id":82,"name":"Cronenberg Rick","status":"unknown","species":"Cronenberg","type":"","gender":"Male","origin":{"name":"Cronenberg Earth","url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/12"},"location":{"name":"Earth (C-137)","url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/1"},"image":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/82.jpeg","episode":["https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/6","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/10"],"url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/82","created":"2017-11-30T14:28:54.596Z"},{"id":86,"name":"Cyclops Rick","status":"Dead","species":"Humanoid","type":"","gender":"Male","origin":{"name":"unknown","url":""},"location":{"name":"Citadel of Ricks","url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/3"},"image":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/86.jpeg","episode":["https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/10","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/22","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/28"],"url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/86","created":"2017-11-30T20:53:10.382Z"},{"id":103,"name":"Doofus Rick","status":"unknown","species":"Human","type":"","gender":"Male","origin":{"name":"Earth (J19ζ7)","url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/31"},"location":{"name":"Earth (Replacement Dimension)","url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/20"},"image":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/103.jpeg","episode":["https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/10","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/22"],"url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/103","created":"2017-12-01T12:29:27.984Z"},{"id":119,"name":"Evil Rick","status":"Dead","species":"Humanoid","type":"Robot","gender":"Male","origin":{"name":"unknown","url":""},"location":{"name":"Citadel of Ricks","url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/3"},"image":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/119.jpeg","episode":["https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/10"],"url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/119","created":"2017-12-26T16:17:16.472Z"},{"id":135,"name":"Garment District Rick","status":"Dead","species":"Human","type":"","gender":"Male","origin":{"name":"unknown","url":""},"location":{"name":"Citadel of Ricks","url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/3"},"image":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/135.jpeg","episode":["https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/28"],"url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/135","created":"2017-12-26T20:51:43.614Z"},{"id":164,"name":"Insurance Rick","status":"unknown","species":"Human","type":"","gender":"Male","origin":{"name":"unknown","url":""},"location":{"name":"Citadel of Ricks","url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/3"},"image":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/164.jpeg","episode":["https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/10"],"url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/164","created":"2017-12-29T17:03:08.645Z"},{"id":165,"name":"Investigator Rick","status":"Dead","species":"Human","type":"","gender":"Male","origin":{"name":"unknown","url":""},"location":{"name":"Citadel of Ricks","url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/3"},"image":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/165.jpeg","episode":["https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/28"],"url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/165","created":"2017-12-29T17:05:15.514Z"},{"id":187,"name":"Juggling Rick","status":"unknown","species":"Human","type":"","gender":"Male","origin":{"name":"unknown","url":""},"location":{"name":"Citadel of Ricks","url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/3"},"image":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/187.jpeg","episode":["https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/28"],"url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/187","created":"2017-12-29T18:59:47.440Z"},{"id":215,"name":"Maximums Rickimus","status":"Dead","species":"Human","type":"","gender":"Male","origin":{"name":"unknown","url":""},"location":{"name":"Rick's Memories","url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/126"},"image":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/215.jpeg","episode":["https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/10","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/22","https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/51"],"url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/215","created":"2017-12-30T14:27:55.489Z"}]}
```

Comment: not sure what you mean by that but if you want the first item in the array use `data[0]`

Comment: "*i want to select a certain index to select that object*" - you mean like `data[0]`? "*but i cant, i tried multiples methods, but dont work*" - please show the methods you tried and how they didn't work, the output they gave and the output you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
response.json();
```

in most of the cases return an array of objects, just like any other array you can deconstruct it to get the first item

```
const [first] = data;
```

something like:

```
fetch("URL")
    .then((response) => {
      response.json().then((data) => {
      const [anyVar] = data.results; // first index of the array
      console.log(anyVar);
    })
   })
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but is not working, tells me the code that data is not iterable

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(data)), to see it looks like

Comment: seems that is return me a JSON object on string format, how can i convert to JSON object?

Comment: can you update the question to show how the response look like?

Comment: i have edit the original post with the output

Comment: it seems that you want to get the "results", I updated my answer to get the first result

Comment: thanks a lot! the .results what exactle does?